# mySqlAdapter.Fill doesn't return rows after updating db

Tags: c#, mysql, database, ado.net

I use `DataTable/DataAdapter` architecture to mediate between the database and my model objects. I have two tables in my db and two `dataGridView` in two windows forms. At first, I call `GetData` method to fill my first `dataGridView`. It is filled successfully. Then I change any field in it and call `UpdateTableChanges`. Changed rows are added to db successfully too. Then I call `GetData` again to fill second `dataGridView`, but no rows are returned. Also there isn't any error during calling `GetData`  the second time. But when I don't call `UpdateTableChanges` and call `GetData` the second time all rows are returned. There is some problem after `UpdateTableChanges` method. Feeling that this method changes some data in my `_adapter`. All parameters in all methods are correct, because rows are returned if I don't call `UpdateTableChanges`. What need I change to get rows after adapter updates db? Any help will be great. I delete try/catch blocks for better understanding.

```
class DBModel 
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private MySqlDataAdapter _adapter;
    private MySqlConnection _connection;

    public DBModel()
    {
        _connectionString = "SERVER = localhost; DATABASE = transportation; USER ID = root;";
        _connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString); 
        _adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(String.Empty, _connection);
    }

    public BindingSource GetData(string selectCommand)
    {
        var bindingSource = new BindingSource();

        SetMySqlSelectCommand(selectCommand);
        var commandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(_adapter);
        var table = new DataTable();
        _adapter.Fill(table);
        bindingSource.DataSource = table;

        return bindingSource;
    }

    public void UpdateTableChanges(BindingSource bindingSource, string selectCommand)
    {
       SetMySqlSelectCommand(selectCommand);
       _adapter.Update((DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource);
    }

    private void SetMySqlSelectCommand(string selectCommand)
    {
        var mySqlCommand = _connection.CreateCommand();
        mySqlCommand.CommandText = selectCommand;
        _adapter.SelectCommand = mySqlCommand;
    }
```